# Xcode -- default to add new files to all targets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

When I add a new file in Xcode, I get a dialog box asking me which targets I want to add the file to. By default, this dialog has just one target selected. I'd like to select all targets by default. Is this possible?

Comment: If you're looking for this behavior, [please duplicate my bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/): rdar://33034215 `Xcode should add per-project default Target Membership to git / source control`

Answer (score -2):

Xcode remembers the selection you make in the dialog, so when you select all targets once, it should have them all selected by default when you add files the next time.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be remembering to me. Just tried it out. Added a file, checked both checkboxes. Added another file, only one checkbox was checked.

Comment: Strange, works for me. Xcode 4.1, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Cool. I'm on 4.0.2. I look forward to my upgrade!